# What is wrong with my logic in this question?

Tags: java, logic

[image: This is the question]

My logic seems to work for every one of the examples, but when I try to submit it, it comes up as wrong because there is one test input (which is not revealed) that somehow results in my code spitting out "24hours and 10min" which is wrong and that the answer should be "0hours and 10min".

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException { 

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        int x = sc.nextInt();
        int xminutes = sc.nextInt();

        int y = sc.nextInt();
        int yminutes = sc.nextInt();

        int xm = x\*60 + xminutes;

        if (y\<=x)y+=24;

        int ym = y\*60 + yminutes;

        System.out.println("O JOGO DUROU "+((ym-xm)/60)+" HORA(S) E "+ ((ym-xm)%60) +" MINUTO(S)");

    }
}
```

Comment: Think what should happen with input "7 30 7 40". Result should be 0:10, but you calculate 24:10 (7<=7), which is obviously incorrect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume the times are begin=9:10 end=9:20.  The correct answer is 10 minutes, obviously.

Then x = y = 9 and you execute `if (y<=x)y+=24`, which is where the extra 24 comes from.

You need to consider the whole times (xm and ym) in order to decide whether the 'end' is the next day after 'begin', and you must add 24 hours (or 24 * 60 minutes).

Comment: thank you so much! this has helped me out a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Your code will fail for input "7 30 7 40", because you only compare the hours when checking the day-rollover. I suggest to first convert the input into "minute of the day", then calculate the difference. If negative, add 24 hours.

Such exercices are best solved with ([JUnit](https://junit.org/junit5/)) [unit tests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_testing) and pure functions which allow you to test automatically without having to run the program manually and provide input.

```
package example;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import java.util.Scanner;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        final int startHour = sc.nextInt();
        final int startMinutes = sc.nextInt();

        final int endHour = sc.nextInt();
        final int endMinutes = sc.nextInt();

        originalCode(startHour, startMinutes, endHour, endMinutes);
        newCode(startHour, startMinutes, endHour, endMinutes);
    }

    private static void originalCode(final int startHour, final int startMinutes, int endHour, final int endMinutes) {
        int xm = startHour * 60 + startMinutes;

        if (endHour <= startHour) {
            endHour += 24;
        }

        int ym = endHour * 60 + endMinutes;

        System.out.println("O JOGO DUROU " + (ym - xm) / 60 + " HORA(S) E " + (ym - xm) % 60 + " MINUTO(S)");
    }

    private static void newCode(final int startHour, final int startMinutes, int endHour, final int endMinutes) {
        final int diff = getDiffInMinutes(startHour, startMinutes, endHour, endMinutes);
        System.out.println("Duration is " + hoursOfMinutes(diff) + ":" + minutesOfMinutes(diff));
    }

    private static int getDiffInMinutes(
            final int startHour,
            final int startMinutes,
            final int endHour,
            final int endMinutes) {
        final int diff = toMinutes(endHour, endMinutes) - toMinutes(startHour, startMinutes);
        return diff <= 0
                ? diff + 24 * 60
                : diff;
        // or (difficult to understand, not recommended):
//         return (diff + 24 * 60 - 1) % (24 * 60) + 1;
    }

    private static int toMinutes(final int startHour, final int startMinutes) {
        return startHour * 60 + startMinutes;
    }

    private static int minutesOfMinutes(final int minutes) { // that's a weird name ...
        return minutes % 60;
    }

    private static int hoursOfMinutes(final int minutes) {
        return minutes / 60; // integer division
    }

    @Test
    void testHoursOfMinutes() {
        assertEquals(0, hoursOfMinutes(0));
        assertEquals(0, hoursOfMinutes(59));
        assertEquals(1, hoursOfMinutes(60));
        assertEquals(1, hoursOfMinutes(61));
        assertEquals(1, hoursOfMinutes(90));
        assertEquals(23, hoursOfMinutes(1400));
        assertEquals(24, hoursOfMinutes(1440));
    }

    @Test
    void testMinutesOfMinutes() {
        assertEquals(0, minutesOfMinutes(0));
        assertEquals(59, minutesOfMinutes(59));
        assertEquals(0, minutesOfMinutes(60));
        assertEquals(1, minutesOfMinutes(61));
        assertEquals(30, minutesOfMinutes(90));
        assertEquals(20, minutesOfMinutes(1400));
        assertEquals(0, minutesOfMinutes(1440));
    }

    @Test
    void testToMinutes() {
        assertEquals(0, toMinutes(0, 0));
        assertEquals(30, toMinutes(0, 30));
        assertEquals(60, toMinutes(1, 0));
        assertEquals(90, toMinutes(1, 30));
        assertEquals(1440, toMinutes(24, 0));
    }

    @Test
    void testDiffInMinutes() {
        assertEquals(40, getDiffInMinutes(7, 20, 8, 0));
        assertEquals(10, getDiffInMinutes(8, 20, 8, 30));
        assertEquals(23 * 60 + 20, getDiffInMinutes(9, 0, 8, 20));
        assertEquals(23 * 60 + 50, getDiffInMinutes(10, 20, 10, 10));
        // minimum 1 minute, maximum 24 hours
        assertEquals(24 * 60, getDiffInMinutes(11, 0, 11, 0));
    }

    @Test
    void runOriginal() {
        originalCode(7, 20, 8, 0); // 00:40
        originalCode(8, 20, 8, 30); // 00:10
        originalCode(9, 0, 8, 20); // 23:20
        originalCode(10, 20, 10, 10); // 23:50
    }

    @Test
    void runNew() {
        newCode(7, 20, 8, 0); // 00:40
        newCode(8, 20, 8, 30); // 00:10
        newCode(9, 0, 8, 20); // 23:20
        newCode(10, 20, 10, 10); // 23:50
    }
}
```

Of course, nothing prevents you from calculating the difference for hours and minutes separately, but this forces you to keep track of the *carry*.

As you can see from above, each simple functionality is covered by a unit test. You are safe to refactor and not break anything. Smaller things are then combined into more complicated things. Unit tests let you sleep well and allow you to build the solution step by step.

Comment: thank you so much! what do you mean by a unit test? i was wondering if there was some website that could try out all the possible inputs in my code so i could see what input didnt work.

Comment: @Rakan <https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_testing>